# How to Turn on/off wi-fi with a keyboard shortcut in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys, wifi-configuration

Is there any way to assign a keyboard hotkey/shortcut key to enable or disable wi-fi in windows 10 without installing any softwares?

I can do that with a program called hot keyboard. But i don't want to run a program all the time slowing my pc for this little task, i'm already running too much...

Comment: If you want, you can use Win + B(system icon tray area), and then use arrow keys and then turn of the wifi. Or you can use Win + A and use Tab and arrow key combos to turn it off as well.

Comment: There is no single key shortcut unless the manufacturer provides one.

Comment: https://www.howtogeek.com/275715/how-to-turn-wi-fi-on-or-off-with-a-keyboard-or-desktop-shortcut-in-windows/#:~:text=For%20example%2C%20you%20could%20assign,to%20enable%20your%20Wi%2DFi.&text=Note%20that%20these%20keyboard%20shortcuts,or%20in%20your%20Start%20menu. Hi, check if it's helpful to you.

Answer (score 2):

These steps worked for me on Windows 10, build 19043.

1. Create and save a new text file in your preferred text editor, with the contents of the file, `netsh wlan disconnect`. Rename the extension of the text file as `.bat` instead of `.txt`.
2. Double-clicking this `.bat` file will instantly turn off your WiFi. To add a keyboard hotkey, first create a shortcut to this file.
3. Right-click on the shortcut, Properties > Shortcut > Shortcut key. Enter the key combination you prefer. Click `Apply`.

If you wish to reconnect, follow the same steps, replacing the file contents with `netsh wlan connect "<Your_Network_Name>"` (Quotes are necessary).

Comment: Too bad you can't just turn it back on and let it reconnect automatically. I'd need to create a shortcut for each of the 5 or 6 networks I regularly use. Why should that be necessary? It defeats the "Connect automatically" capability.

Answer (score 1):

Try:   `netsh wlan disconnect interface="name of connection"`

And:   `netsh wlan connect interface="name of connection"`

That works fine for me. This will work on any Windows 10 computer.

On my machine (ThinkPad X1), also I can press <kbd>Fn</kbd>-<kbd>F8</kbd> and that disconnects Wi-Fi. This will depend upon your particular PC.  Look at its docs / help.

Comment: Do you not have to run these as an administrator?

Comment: I would have to test. Standard users normally do not need this feature